# Force download via AJAX

Tags: html, ajax, forms, post, download

I'm looking for a way to `POST` data to a backend script, use it to generate a temporary file on the fly (temporary in that it's dynamically generated and not saved to disk on the server), and then offer it to the client as a download.

I have the backend script functioning fine.  The problem is that I haven't yet found a way to get the download prompt via an AJAX call.

If I weren't `POST`ing data, I would just use something like:

```
window.location.href = 'path/to/my/script.php';
```

Is what I'm after even possible?  Can it be done without resorting to "hacks" like dynamically injecting a form into the DOM and submitting it, or opening up another browser window, etc.?

Comment: Could you alter the `target` of the form into a hidden `iframe` and then submit that?  If you're dealing with any viewstate information (like in ASP.NET) you'd have to call the same page

Comment: You want to have the current page act like it posted a form that isn't visible, but don't want to "resort" to having a form that isn't visible, posted. Why?

Comment: @JonHanna: The user takes actions on the UI which are constructed into a JS object.  When the user saves, I want to POST this JS object and some other relevant bits of data, have the server construct a "file", and then prompt the client to download.

Comment: @freefaller: There is no form, so no.

Comment: @arxanas: I can't POST the data using that method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. make POST request;
2. create the resource;
3. answer with the resource path;
4. `window.location.href = resourcePath`.
5. [optional] want to secure such resource from third part download? Attach a CSRF token, and make the resource available only if CSRF check is passed - otherwise congratulations, you just won a 403 puppy!

If the resource has proper headers, the browser will ask you to save / open it with specific app. / an so.

Comment: I mentioned in my question that the content is not saved to disk on the server.  That would necessitate me running cleanup crons and maintaining disk space, etc.

Comment: Just generate resource on GET instead, if necessary with some specific request parameters.

Comment: @drrcknlsn I meant resource in a RESTful way - you may generate the binary answer later - just save in session the stuff you got via `POST`, and reget it via the id you provided in the first answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that without a classic form submit unless you can somehow make the download available via GET.

However, doing that would be a good idea anyway since download managers etc. often don't work well with POST - so simply make your script generate a temporary URL and then redirect to that URL using the JavaScript you already posted in your question.